# Angular js main Controller failing to load in ipad safari browser but works fine with chrome in ipad as well as desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, ipad

I am facing a peculiar problem where single page angular js web app  fails to load on ipad safari browser  where as it works fine in chrome in ipad as well as in desktop.There are no errors reported in console or any javascript exceptions in chrome either in desktop, also the app works fine in safari browser in windows desktop, i have got struck on how to resolve this.

These are my following code snippets

Index.html is my main html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <title></title>

    <!--Libraries-->

    <!--<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>-->


    <script src="Resources/angular.min-1.3.js"></script>


    <script src="Resources/jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="resources/scripts/angular-touch.js"></script>


    <script src="Resources/jquery-ui.js"></script>


    <script src="Resources/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




    <script src="Resources/angular-animate.js"></script>



    <script src="Resources/angular-scenario.js"></script>


    <script src="Resources/ngCanvasGauge.js"></script>


    <script src="Resources/nstar/js/wow.js"></script>

   <script> alert('wow.js'); </script>
   <script>
  var test = get_browser_info();

    alert(test.name);
    alert(test.version);

      function get_browser_info() {
        var ua = navigator.userAgent, tem, M = ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [];
        if (/trident/i.test(M[1])) {
            tem = /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || [];
            return { name: 'IE', version: (tem[1] || '') };
        }
        if (M[1] === 'Chrome') {
            tem = ua.match(/\bOPR\/(\d+)/)
            if (tem != null) { return { name: 'Opera', version: tem[1] }; }
        }
        M = M[2] ? [M[1], M[2]] : [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
        if ((tem = ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i)) != null) { M.splice(1, 1, tem[1]); }
        return {
            name: M[0],
            version: M[1]
        };
    }






</script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <!--filters-->
    <script src="resources/filters.js"></script>


    <!--Config files-->
    <script src="Config/ServiceConstants.js"></script>

    <!--Services-->
    <script src="Services/LoginService.js"></script>
    <script src="Services/MenuService.js"></script>
    <script src="Services/ConfigService.js"></script>
    <script src="Services/DashboardService.js"></script>
    <script src="Services/HomeService.js"></script>
    <script src="Services/UserService.js"></script>
    <script src="Services/VehicleService.js"></script>
    <script src="Services/MessagingService.js"></script>
    <script src="Services/VehicleDetailsService.js"></script>
    <script src="Services/UserDetailsService.js"></script>
    <script src="Services/PasswordService.js"></script>
    <script src="Services/SystemService.js"></script>
    <script src="Services/HistoryService.js"></script>
    <script src="Services/runtimeConfigService.js"></script>
    <script src="Services/NetworkConfigService.js"></script>
    <script src="Services/LocationService.js"></script>
    <script src="Services/SftpManagerService.js"></script>
    <script src="Services/uploadService.js"></script>
    <script src="Services/PackageUpdateService.js"></script>

<!--Directives-->
    <script src="Directives/MenuDirective.js"></script>
    <script src="directives/nstardirectives.js"></script>

    <!--Controllers-->
    <script src="Controllers/LoginController.js"></script>
    <script src="Controllers/MenuController.js"></script>
    <script src="Controllers/ContentController.js"></script>
    <script src="Controllers/ConfigurationController.js"></script>
    <script src="Controllers/HomeController.js"></script>
    <script src="Controllers/DashboardController.js"></script>
    <script src="Controllers/HomeController.js"></script>
    <script src="Controllers/HeaderController.js"></script>
    <script src="Controllers/UserController.js"></script>
    <script src="Controllers/UserDetailsController.js"></script>
    <script src="Controllers/VehicleController.js"></script>
    <script src="Controllers/HistoryController.js"></script>
    <script src="Controllers/VehicleDetailsController.js"></script>
    <script src="Controllers/SystemController.js"></script>
    <script src="Controllers/PasswordController.js"></script>
    <script src="Controllers/RuntimeConfigController.js"></script>
    <script src="Controllers/NetworkConfigController.js"></script>
    <script src="Controllers/MessagingController.js"></script>
    <script src="Controllers/LocationController.js"></script>
    <script src="Controllers/SftpManagerController.js"></script>
    <script src="Controllers/UploadController.js"></script>
    <script src="Controllers/PackageUpdateController.js"></script>


    <!--css-->
    <link href="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!--<link href="Resources/css/ipl-wait-spinner.css" rel="stylesheet" />-->
    <link href="Resources/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Resources/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Resources/css/angular-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />



</head>
<body id="container" ng-app="IesApp" ng-controller="mainController">

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">Please Confirm</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            {{modalText}}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>

    <div id="splash" class="splash ng-cloak">
        <div id="ipl-splash-logo"></div>
        <div id="ipl-splash-loader"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ng-cloak" ng-if="theme !== 'NSTAR'">
        <script src="Resources/jarvis.widget.js"></script>
        <script src="Resources/jarvisWidgetModule.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="Resources/ipl-wait-spinner.js"></script>-->
        <script src="Resources/scripts/i18next.js"></script>
        <script src="Resources/scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.1.min.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="Resources/scripts/responsivetables.js"></script>-->
        <script src="Resources/ipl-navigation.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="Resources/scripts/ng-map.min.js"></script>-->

        <link href="Resources/css/plugin-jarviswidget.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="Resources/css/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="Resources/css/login.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="Resources/css/content.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="Resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="Resources/css/ipl-navigation.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="Resources/css/customcontrols.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="Resources/css/ngCanvasGauge.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="Resources/css/TextScroll.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="Resources/css/responsivetables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="Resources/css/Fileupload.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <header ipl-header id="header" ng-include="'Resources/app/Includes/header.html'"></header>
        <aside id="left-panel"><span ng-include="'Resources/app/Includes/left-panel.html'"></span></aside>
        <main id="main" role="main">
            <div id="login" ng-controller="loginController" ng-include="'Templates/Login.html'" ng-if="isloggedIn === false"></div>
            <div ng-controller="contentController">
                <div id="content" ng-include="'Templates/Dashboard.html'" ng-if="isloggedIn === undefined && PageName === 'Dashboard' && theme === 'Default'"></div>
                <div id="content" ng-include="'Templates/pepco/dashboard.html'" ng-if="isloggedIn === undefined && PageName === 'Dashboard' && theme === 'PEPCO'"></div>
                <div id="content" ng-include="'Templates/Home.html'" ng-if="isloggedIn === undefined && PageName === 'Home'"></div>
                <div id="content" ng-if="isloggedIn === true" ng-include="contentTemplate()"></div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <div class="page-footer"><span ng-include="'Resources/app/Includes/footer.html'"></span></div>
        <link href="Resources/css/smartadmin-production.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </div>
    <div class="ng-cloak" ng-if="theme === 'NSTAR'">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="Resources/nstar/js/timeline.js"></script>


        <script src='Resources/nstar/js/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='Resources/nstar/js/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='Resources/nstar/js/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='Resources/nstar/js/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='Resources/nstar/js/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasOverlay.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='Resources/nstar/js/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='Resources/nstar/js/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='Resources/nstar/js/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='Resources/nstar/js/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='Resources/nstar/js/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.highlighter.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='Resources/nstar/js/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.cursor.min.js'></script>


        <style type='text/css'>
            .jqplot-yaxis-label, .jqplot-y2axis-label {
                /* Rotate labels -90* */
                -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
                -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
                -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
                -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
                transform: rotate(-90deg);
                -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
                -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
                -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
                -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
                transform-origin: 50% 50%;
                filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
            }

            .jqplot-y2axis-label {
                margin-right: -24px;
            }

            .jqplot-point-label {
                color: White;
            }
        </style>
        <!--NSTAR-->
        <link href="Resources/nstar/extras/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="Resources/nstar/fonts/flaticon.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="Resources/nstar/css/nstarstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="Resources/nstar/css/timeline.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="Resources/nstar/extras/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='Resources/nstar/css/jquery.jqplot.min.css' />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/nstar/css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/nstar/css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="Resources/nstar/fonts/font-awesome.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="Resources/nstar/fonts/roboto-regular.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/nstar/css/jquery.ptTimeSelect.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/nstar/css/responsive.css" />
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/nstar/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" />-->

        <div id="content" ng-include="'Templates/nstar/MainMenu.html'"></div> <br /><br /><br /><br />
        <div ng-controller="contentController">
            <div id="login" ng-controller="loginController" ng-include="'Templates/nstar/Login.html'" ng-if="isloggedIn === false"></div>
            <div id="content" ng-include="'Templates/nstar/dashboard.html'" ng-if="isloggedIn === undefined && PageName === 'Dashboard' "></div>
            <div id="content" ng-if="isloggedIn === true" ng-include="contentTemplate()"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

my Main angular controller snippet is

```js
try
{
alert('app js started');
var IesApp = angular.module("IesApp", ['ngTouch', 'ipl.jarvisWidgets', 'ui.bootstrap', 'IplApp.navigation', 'IesApp.Config','IesApp.Services', 'IesApp.Controllers', 'IesApp.Directives']);//, 'ngMap']);
alert('module init');
angular.module("IesApp.Config", []);
alert('module Config');
angular.module("IesApp.Services", []);
alert('module Services');
angular.module("IesApp.Controllers", []);
alert('module Controllers');
angular.module("IesApp.Directives", []);
alert('module Directives');

try
{

IesApp.controller("mainController", ['$rootScope', 'menuService', function ($rootScope, menuService) {
alert('main controller started');
    $rootScope.Headers = {};
    $rootScope.ChargeSessionID = '00000000000000000000000000000000';
    $rootScope.SelectedUserID = '00000000000000000000000000000000';
    $rootScope.UserID = '00000000000000000000000000000000';
    $rootScope.UserName = "";
    $rootScope.VehicleID = '00000000000000000000000000000000';
    $rootScope.UserCookie;
    $rootScope.PassCookie;
    $rootScope.SsId;
    $rootScope.SsPid;
    $rootScope.PageName = "Dashboard";
    $rootScope.isloggedIn = undefined;
    $rootScope.themeChanged = false;
    $rootScope.AppVersion = '';
    $rootScope.theme;
    $rootScope.KillSession = false;
    $rootScope.TSsId = undefined;
    $rootScope.TSsPid = undefined;
    $rootScope.CurrentPage;
    $rootScope.ServerDateInfo;

    $rootScope.setCookie = function (name,data,days) {
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        }
        else var expires = "";
        document.cookie = name + "=" + data + expires + "; path=/";
    }

    $rootScope.getCookie = function (name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }
        return '';
    }

    $rootScope.flushCookie = function(name) {
        $rootScope.setCookie(name, "", -1);
}

    $rootScope.LoadCookie = function () {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
        $rootScope.SsId = this.getCookie("ss-id");
        $rootScope.SsPid = this.getCookie("ss-pid");
        $rootScope.UserCookie = this.getCookie("userCookie");
        $rootScope.PassCookie = this.getCookie("passCookie");
        $rootScope.UserName = this.getCookie("uname");
        $rootScope.CurrentPage = this.getCookie("Page");
        $rootScope.UserID = this.getCookie("uid");
        $rootScope.SelectedUserID = $rootScope.UserID;

        $rootScope.PrepareHeader();
}

    $rootScope.PrepareHeader = function () {
        $rootScope.Headers = {
            "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "pass": $rootScope.PassCookie,
            "user": $rootScope.UserCookie,
            "ss-id": $rootScope.SsId,
            "ss-pid": $rootScope.SsPid,
            "Page": $rootScope.CurrentPage
    };
}
$rootScope.LoadCookie();
menuService.getMenuResponse();
alert('main controller ended');
}]);

}
catch(err)
{
 alert('main controller error '+err.message);
}
}
catch(err1)
{
 alert('app js error '+err1.message);
}
```

My main controller is not all getting called in ipad safari at all nor it is showing any error, I commented all the code inside controller to check if any for syntax error but none could be found out.

all i am doing in my controller is injecting the rootscope and menu service modules.

code snippet for menu service is

```js
try
{
angular.module("IesApp.Services")

.service("menuService", ['$http', '$rootScope',  'Constants', function ($http, $rootScope,  Constants) {
    var menuItems = {};
    this.menuItemSelected;
alert('menu service started');
    this.getDefaultPage = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
            if (menuItems[i].SubMenu !== undefined) {
                for (var j = 0; j < menuItems[i].SubMenu.length; j++) {
                    if (menuItems[i].SubMenu[j].SubMenu !== undefined) {
                        for (var k = 0; k < menuItems[i].SubMenu[j].SubMenu.length; k++) {
                            if (menuItems[i].SubMenu[j].SubMenu[k].IsDefault === true) {
                                return menuItems[i].SubMenu[j].SubMenu[k].URL;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if (menuItems[i].SubMenu[j].IsDefault === true) {
                            return menuItems[i].SubMenu[j].URL;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                if (menuItems[i].IsDefault === true) {
                    return menuItems[i].URL;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var setMenuServiceResponse = function (data) {
        menuItems = data.MenuItems;        
    };

    this.setMenuItemSelected = function (item) {
        if ($rootScope.isloggedIn == true || item == "Dashboard" || item == "Home") {
            if (item == "NewUser") {
                $rootScope.SelectedUserID = '00000000000000000000000000000000';
            }
            else if (item == "MyProfile") {
                $rootScope.SelectedUserID = $rootScope.UserID;
            }

            if (item == "Dashboard" || item == "Home") {
                if ($rootScope.isloggedIn == false)
                    $rootScope.isloggedIn = undefined;
            }
            $rootScope.PageName = item;
            this.menuItemSelected = item;
            $rootScope.$broadcast("MenuChanged");
        }
        else {
            $rootScope.isloggedIn = false;
            $rootScope.PageName = "Login";
            this.menuItemSelected = item;
            $rootScope.$broadcast("MenuChanged");
        }
alert('menu service set cookie start');
        $rootScope.setCookie("Page", item, 1);
alert('menu service set cookie end');
    };

    this.getPathFromMenuitem = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
            if (menuItems[i].SubMenu !== undefined) {
                for (var j = 0; j < menuItems[i].SubMenu.length; j++) {
                    if (menuItems[i].SubMenu[j].SubMenu !== undefined) {
                        for (var k = 0; k < menuItems[i].SubMenu[j].SubMenu.length; k++) {
                            if (menuItems[i].SubMenu[j].SubMenu[k].Id === this.menuItemSelected) {
                                var path = menuItems[i].SubMenu[j].SubMenu[k].URL;
                                $rootScope.CurrentPage = menuItems[i].SubMenu[j].SubMenu[k].Id;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if (menuItems[i].SubMenu[j].Id === this.menuItemSelected) {
                            var path = menuItems[i].SubMenu[j].URL;
                            $rootScope.CurrentPage = menuItems[i].SubMenu[j].Id;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                if (menuItems[i].Id === this.menuItemSelected) {
                    var path = menuItems[i].URL;
                    $rootScope.CurrentPage = menuItems[i].Id
                }
            }
        }
        //if page changed updated the cookie
alert('menu service set cookie start 2');
            $rootScope.setCookie("Page", $rootScope.CurrentPage, 1);
alert('menu service set cookie end 2');
           // $rootScope.$broadcast("Page_Changed");
        return path;
    }

    this.getMenuServiceResponse = function () {
        return menuItems;
    };

    this.setMenuVisibility = function (id, visible) {
        for (index = 0; index < menuItems.length; index++) {
            if (menuItems[index] !== undefined && menuItems[index].Id === id) {
                menuItems[index].Visibility = visible;
                return;
            }
            if (menuItems[index].SubMenu !== undefined) {
                for (subIndex = 0; subIndex < menuItems[index].SubMenu.length; subIndex++) {
                    if (menuItems[index].SubMenu[subIndex] !== undefined && menuItems[index].SubMenu[subIndex].Id === id) {
                        menuItems[index].SubMenu[subIndex].Visibility = visible;
                        return;
                    }
                    if (menuItems[index].SubMenu[subIndex].SubMenu !== undefined) {
                        for (supIndex = 0; supIndex < menuItems[index].SubMenu[subIndex].SubMenu.length; supIndex++) {
                            if (menuItems[index].SubMenu[subIndex].SubMenu[supIndex] != undefined && menuItems[index].SubMenu[subIndex].SubMenu[supIndex].Id === id) {
                                menuItems[index].SubMenu[subIndex].SubMenu[supIndex].Visibility = visible;
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var setSubMenuUrl = function (menuItem, id, url) {
        if (menuItem !== undefined)
        {
            if (menuItem.SubMenu !== undefined) {
                for (index = 0; index < menuItem.SubMenu.length; index++) {
                    if (menuItem.SubMenu[index] === undefined) {
                        return;
                    }
                    else {
                        if (menuItem.SubMenu[index].SubMenu === undefined) {
                            if (menuItem.SubMenu[index].Id === id) {
                                menuItem.SubMenu[index].URL = url;
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            setSubMenuUrl(menuItem.SubMenu[index].SubMenu, id, url);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (var mIndex = 0; mIndex < menuItem.length; mIndex++) {
                    if (menuItem[mIndex].Id === id) {
                        menuItem[mIndex].URL = url;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }        
    }

    this.setMenuUrl = function (id, url) {
        for (index = 0; index < menuItems.length; index++) {
            if (menuItems[index] !== undefined) {
                if (menuItems[index].SubMenu === undefined) {
                    if (menuItems[index].Id === id) {
                        menuItems[index].URL = url;                        
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    setSubMenuUrl(menuItems[index].SubMenu, id, url);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    this.getMenuResponse = function () {
        var req = {
            method: Constants.Menu.method,
            url: Constants.Menu.url,
            headers: $rootScope.Headers
        }
        $http(req).success(function (data) {
            setMenuServiceResponse(data);
            if ($rootScope.Headers.user === undefined || $rootScope.Headers.user === '') {
                $rootScope.isLoggedIn = undefined;
                $rootScope.pageName = 'Dashboard';
                $rootScope.UserName = "";
                $rootScope.StationName = "";
            }
            else {
                $rootScope.isloggedIn = true;
            }

            $rootScope.AppVersion = data.AppVersion;
            $rootScope.theme = data.Theme;
            $rootScope.StationName = data.StationName;
        }).error(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }

    this.getServerDateTimeInfoResponse = function () {
        var req = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/serverDateInfo',
        }
        $http(req).success(function (data) {
            $rootScope.ServerDateInfo = data;
        }).error(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }

}]);
}
catch(err)
{
alert('menu service error '+err.message);
}
```

Any help regarding this is much appreciated and thanks

Comment: please reduce the code..Its too big to read..keep relevant code only..

Comment: Did you tried to debug the code with remote console?

Comment: yes i  had alerts and tried and did debugging